# Executable C++ file keeps closing without even showing the resulting product

Tags: c++, windows

We've got a task to basically write up a code that accepts input from the user, and then multiplies that input by itself. However, for some reason, when I run the program, it'll accept an input, then end, without showing the product at all.

For reference, here's the code used.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double dValue1, product;
    cout<<"Please input your daily budget.\n";
    cin>>dValue1;
    product=dValue1*dValue1;
    cout<<product;
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

EDIT: For anyone interested in a quick (but not permanent) fix to this problem, I've been adding #include<stdio.h> and using getchar(); getchar(); to at least allow me to see the output !! Hope this will help anyone struggling like I was. ^w^

Comment: You aren't writing a newline or flushing the buffer (`std::endl`) after the output.

Comment: @gspr I would expect `cin` to automatically do flush at the end of the program. Maybe it's implementation dependent

Comment: Code works perfectly fine https://godbolt.org/z/13dshr76h . The problem might be how do you execute the program?

Comment: you could force the output with a std::flush as well. The using namespace std isn't a good style.

Comment: I think some old versions of mingw fail to automatically flush `cout` at the end of the program, update to a more modern version or add an explicit flush

Comment: @Patryk I usually just run the executable file in file explorer, but what you brought up might be the case, seeing as it's done this before on previous programs. Thank you ^w^

Comment: @AlanBirtles Ooh, that could be a possibility. I just checked, and the MinGW version I'm currently running is 6.3.0. I'll double-check to see if it checks out >-<

Comment: I would add `windows` tag as this is specific to the platform and the way it handles console apps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This has everything to do with *how* you are running your program.

On Windows, the system recognizes that the program is tagged as needing an output terminal and creates an instance of the Windows Console for you.

Your program then runs without problem, printing its output to the console, *then terminates*.

Since the process terminated, Windows cleans up and closes the Windows Console window that was attached to your (now non-existing) application. Your user never gets the chance to see the output.

*The correct way* to fix this is to simply run the program from the Command window directly. Use Explorer to navigate to the executable as usual, but instead of clicking on the file you should click on the Navigation Bar and type `cmd` and press Enter.

This gets you a Windows Console opened to the folder containing your executable. Type its name and press Enter to see it run. For example, if your program is named "quux.exe" then type `quux` and press Enter.

When you are done with the terminal window, just close it by clicking on the "X" button like with any other Windows application.

*Why not use getch() or something like that?*

Because it assumes that your user is a human typing things in. That may not be the case, and programs that require a human to be present when not needed are quickly discarded for programs that don't.